# How to Span Element Across Multiple Divs CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner to Html & CSS and have a probably really simple question, but I just can't seem to find the answer: How could you span an html element(child div, text, etc.) across multiple divs using only CSS & Html(no Javascript/JS)? I'm building a simple event calendar(using HTML+CSS) and am currently working on multiple day events.

```css
html, body {
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background:white;
  height:100%;
}

b{
  font-family:calibri;
  padding-left:10px;
}

#container{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width:300px;
  padding-top:50px;
}

.colorone{
  background:#FFEB3B;
  width:150px;
  height: 150px;
  float:left;
}
.colortwo{
  width:150px;
  height: 150px;
  background:#8BC34A;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
<div id="container">
  <div class="colorone"><b>4</b>
   </div>
    
  <div class="colortwo"><b>5</b>
   </div>
    </div>  
    
  </body>
    
</html>
```

Desired result:
[image]

The blue div/rectangle should also be able to span more than two parent divs if wanted.

I've searched and researched online & on StackOverflow but I still can't seem to find the answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You would use a higher z-index on the blue div and float it above the other two.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_context_example_1

Comment: in your case you don't actually need an element to span multiple elements, you simply need to highlight multiple elements. CSS `background` is how to set this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick example using your code with a few changes. I added the position to the container and the 3rd element and set the z-index to 2 on the div with the class of .colorthree.

```js
var width = 0,
    container = $('#container');

container.children('div').each(function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('colorthree')) {
    width += $(this).width();
  }
});
container.width(width);
$('.colorthree').width(width-20);
```

```css
html, body {
left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background:white;
  height:100%;
}

b{
  font-family:calibri;
  padding-left:10px;
}

#container{
  margin: 20px auto;
  width:300px;
  height: 150px;
  position:relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.colorone, .colortwo, .colorfour {
  width:150px;
  height: 150px;
  background:#8BC34A;
  overflow:hidden;
  float:left;
}
.colorone{
  background:#FFEB3B;
}
.colorfour {
  background: red;
}
.colorthree {
  z-index: 2;
  top: 20px;
  left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  width:90%;
  height: 40px;
  background:blue;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="container">
      <div class="colorone"><b>1</b></div> 
      <div class="colortwo"><b>2</b></div>
      <div class="colorfour"><b>4</b></div>
      <div class="colorthree"><b>3</b></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: thanks for your answer but i just discovered i would have to manually adjust the width of the blue (spanned) div every time i adjust the number if divs to span across. is there any way to make it so i just need to change the number of divs to span across? Thank you!

Comment: You could use. % for the width if that helps width: 95% or something. Another option would be use some JavaScript to set the width dynamically.

Comment: I added some jQuery to set the width dynamically by calculating the width from the nested divs and then set the width of the container and the div with the class of colorthree.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `position: absolute`

No javascript needed, only with html and css

```css
html,
body {
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: white;
  height: 100%;
}

b {
  font-family: calibri;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.colorone {
  background: #FFEB3B;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
}

.colortwo {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #8BC34A;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.colorthree {
  background-color: blue;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <span class="colorthree">I'm Span!</span>
    <div class="colorone"><b>4</b>
    </div>

    <div class="colortwo"><b>5</b>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```