# Make Element Span Multiple Cells/Grids In A Table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an HTML table like the following one, along with an event:

```css
table#demotable {
      table-layout: fixed ;
      width: 100% ;
      border-collapse: collapse ;
      border: 1px black solid ;
    }
    table#demotable td {
      width: 50% ;
      border: 1px black solid ;
      padding: 10px ;
      height: 60px;
    }
    table#demotable caption {
      font-style: italic ;
    }
```

```html
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css'><link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <b>Trebelle Elementary Agenda</b>
    <table id="demotable">
    <tr>
      <td id="1"><a class="event d-block p-1 pl-2 pr-2 mb-1 rounded text-truncate small bg-info text-white" title="School Carnival">Zoom Meeting</a></td>
      <td id="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="3"></td>
      <td id="4"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

With HTML, CSS, and a little JS if needed, how could I make this event go across multiple table cells, for example, cells with id 1-3?
Also, I would not like to have to do 3 `<a>` tags, one in each cell that the event will need to span across, because that would be a lot of work and it would generally not be good practice.
The end result should look something like:[image]
Things I've tried:

- [Move Child's Overflow To Next Row If Current Row's Width Too Narrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62973720/move-childs-overflow-to-next-row-if-current-rows-width-too-narrow#comment111369500_62973720)
- [How to Span Element Across Multiple Divs CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62964315/how-to-span-element-across-multiple-divs-css/62964511#62964511)

I've tried to search something up, but all the answers I could find wouldn't work for me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Pretty much similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62973720/move-childs-overflow-to-next-row-if-current-rows-width-too-narrow#comment111369500_62973720) has been asked just yesterday.

Comment: @VXp That question seems to be only for elements to span multiple divs, instead of more than one table cell.

Comment: Here's a similar question and answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62964315/how-to-span-element-across-multiple-divs-css/62964511#62964511

Comment: You can adjust/modify your markup.

Comment: @osekmedia I can't span an element multiple rows with the question you linked.

Comment: Ahh, sorry I misunderstood.